# How to ignore rest of gRPC(java) ServerInterceptor when ServerCall closed in first ServerInterceptro?

Tags: java, server, interceptor, grpc

I bind 2 ServerInterceptor on a gRPC service.

In the first interceptor, ServerCall has been closed, but the second interceptor is still involved.

So how to skip the rest of interceptors while ServerCall is closed in first interceptor?

first interceptor:

```
public class FirstInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {

      @Override
      public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
           ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call,
           Metadata headers,
           ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {

           if(...){
               ...
               return Contexts.interceptCall(context, call, headers, next);
           }else{
               ...
               call.close(Status.UNAUTHENTICATED.withDescription("@FST_INTCP"),GrpcUtil.getMetadataWithErrMsg(e));
               return next.startCall(new ForwardingServerCall.SimpleForwardingServerCall<ReqT, RespT>(call) {}, headers);
           }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interceptors are not required to call `next`. If you are closing the `ServerCall` during `interceptCall()`, then there is no need to call `next` because nothing else in the chain will be able to respond.

So the code would look like:

```
public class FirstInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
             ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call,
             Metadata headers,
             ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
         if(...) {
             ...
             return Contexts.interceptCall(context, call, headers, next);
         } else {
             ...
             call.close(Status.UNAUTHENTICATED.withDescription("@FST_INTCP"),
                 GrpcUtil.getMetadataWithErrMsg(e));
             return new ServerCall.Listener() {};
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since interceptors are chained, you can get the closing event from the Listener.  Instead of directly returning the `ServerCall.Listener` you get from  next, you can create a new one which delegates:

```
ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> delegate = Contexts.interceptCall(context, call, headers, next);
return new SimpleForwardingServerCallListener<ReqT>(delegate) {
  boolean cancelled;
  @Override
  void onCancel() {
    cancelled = true;
  }

  @Override 
  void onMessage(Req req) {
    if (cancelled) {
      return;
    }
    // normal logic here.
  }
}
```

See [SimpleForwardingServerCallListener](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/ForwardingServerCallListener.java#L40).

You can do something similar for `ServerCall` using `SimpleForwardingServerCall` going in the other direction.