# The gRPC server obtains the request header

Tags: java, postgresql, grpc

I build the server of Java gRPC and want to obtain the data transmitted by the client through the request header. At present, I can only use the ServerInterceptor class to intercept the parsing request header Metadata, but I want to obtain it during service operation. What is the solution?

I tried to access and transfer data through redis, but the gRPC I wrote is multi-data source, the same client request has multiple, if different clients to me a request, but they carry different request headers, other interface names and parameters are the same, It's possible that the request header of a later request will overwrite the redis result of the previous request header, so I can't guarantee the consistency of request and request header!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `io.grpc.Context` to propagate the value to the service implementation, using `Contexts.interceptCall()`. The [jwt-auth example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/f4cda008ee1c0e10de8575e1b4be6841d5364b72/examples/example-jwt-auth/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/jwtauth/JwtServerInterceptor.java#L64-L66) does this as well as some other StackOverflow [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44773152/4690866) [and](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71473852/4690866) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40113309/4690866).

Essentially, you just create a new Context with the information you want to communicate, and use `Contexts.interceptCall()` to make it available to the service as a ThreadLocal. If your service does processing on another thread, you need to either propagate the Context to that other thread or save the value ahead-of-time.

```java
public class AddToContextInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {
  // Context keys use reference equality, so the consumer of the value
  // must use this specific object.
  public static final Context.Key<MyObject> MY_KEY = Context.key("MY_KEY");

  @Override
  public <ReqT,RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
      ServerCall<ReqT,RespT> call, Metadata headers,
      ServerCallHandler<ReqT,RespT> next) {
    Context newContext =
        Context.current().withValue(MY_KEY, metadata.get(SOME_KEY));
    return Contexts.interceptCall(newContext, call, headers, next);
  }
}

// In the service:
MyObject o = AddToContextInterceptor.MY_KEY.get();
```