# gRPC Access the headers from anywhere

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I have a gRPC server interceptor that gets the metadata from a request and save them in a context like

```
@Slf4j
@GrpcGlobalServerInterceptor
public class ServerSideInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(final ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call,
                                                                 final Metadata headers,
                                                                 final ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {

        log.info("Setting user context, metadata {}", headers);

        Context context = Context.current();

        return Contexts.interceptCall(context, call, headers, next);
    }
}
```

the metadata comes in like

> Setting user context, metadata
> Metadata(accept-country=USA,app=SellerApp,authorization=Bearer
> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAig,grpc-accept-encoding=identity,deflate,gzip,accept-encoding=identity,user-agent=grpc-node-js/1.8.10,content-type=application/grpc)

How can I access the context from another class within the service and do a validation like this

```
// Check if the country header exists
    String country = (headers.get("Accept-Country") == null)
            ? headers.get("Accept-Country")
            : headers.get("Accept-Country");

    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(country)){
      return  ResponseWrapper.builder()
              .code(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value())
              .message("Please provide 'Accept-Country' header")
              .build();
    }
```

How can I access the data from the server interceptor? and use it from anywhere within the Microservices?

Answer (score 0):

The general pattern for this in a ServerInterceptor is:

- Extract the header value you are interested in from Metadata
- Create a new copy of the Context with your metadata included with a Context.withValue() call
- Pass on the new Context in the Contexts.interceptCall() call

After this is done your application logic can access the metadata in the current context (Context.currentContext()).

For some more info on this look at this similar question: [The gRPC server obtains the request header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75000504/the-grpc-server-obtains-the-request-header)